# Unable to connect to CopSSH when running Windows service, works when running sshd directly

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh, sshd, copssh

I've been using CopSSH (that uses OpenSSH and Cygwin, so I don't know which of the three is the problem) as my SSH server application at home on Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit.  I have used it for about a year with no real problems, other than it sometimes takes 2 or 3 connection attempts to get through, but it's always worked within a few attempts.

A few days ago, it just stopped working.  The Windows service is still running, and I've rebooted, restarted the service, etc. with no change.  On the client (using Putty on Windows), I get the message "Software caused connection abort".  On the server, my event viewer registers the following:

```
fatal: Write failed: Socket operation on non-socket
```

I finally got it working, but only by executing sshd.exe directly from the command line on the server.  No special flags or options, just straight execution, and then when I connect remotely, it goes through.

I do have firewall and anti-virus software which appears to be configured properly, but the fact that things work when running sshd.exe also indicates that the firewall is fine.

I thought the service and executable did exactly the same thing, but apparently there's some difference.  Does anyone have any ideas on where I should look for the problem?

If I can't find something, I suppose I can write a Windows service or scheduled task that fires off sshd.exe directly and ensures that it stays running, but that's kind of a last resort, since it's just wrapping around something that should already work.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: FYI: Things magically started working again yesterday with no explanation why...

Except now I'm still getting the "you already have a console session" error, after I connected once, disconnected, then attempted to connect again.  Who knows why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this question got me the tumbleweed badge, so I guess it's a pretty good question...

I did find out that running sshd.exe directly isn't the answer - it works for normal SSH connections, but it won't let me RDP in, telling me I already have a console open and can't open another.  Doesn't make sense to me, but such is life.

I think my next step is probably to dump CopSSH and try again from scratch.